# How can I find LayerGroup for a given object in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

So, I have a LayerGroup with polylines, points, etc. in some Layers.
A certain Polyline has the handler:

```
Polyline.on('click', lineHelper);
```

Can I find out in this handler which LayerGroup the Polyline belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I find out in this handler which `LayerGroup` the `Polyline` belongs to?

No, since a `Polyline` (or any other `Layer`) can belong to zero, one, or several `LayerGroup`s at once; a `Layer` doesn't keep a list of `LayerGroup`s it's part of (it can belong to `LayerGroup`s not on the map the layer is in).

You might want to iterate all known `LayerGroup`s and run [`hasLayer()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layergroup-haslayer) on each, or (if you use the same event handler for several layers) use [`FeatureGroup`s](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#featuregroup) instead of `LayerGroup`s, and attach the event handler to the `FeatureGroup` just once (instead of attaching an event handler to each individual `Layer`).

Comment: No way to get `LayerGroup`s...

Comment: And `oneLayer.hasLayer(otnerLayer)` return FALSE if **otnerLayer** is not a direct child of **oneLayer**.